# problems with CPAN::Tarzip running on a MiniCPAN mirror

Tags: windows, linux, perl, cpan, minicpan

I created a local repository with minicpan in a Linux box, and then moved it to a Windows that has no access to online CPAN. But I'm getting this error messages when I try to use it:

```
cpan> install PowerBuilder::ORCA
Reading 'C:\Perl\minicpan\authors\01mailrc.txt.gz'
Use of uninitialized value $command in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Perl\site\lib/CPAN/Tarzip.pm line 161.
"-qdt" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
............................................................................DONE
Reading 'C:\Perl\minicpan\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz'
Use of uninitialized value $command in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Perl\site\lib/CPAN/Tarzip.pm line 161.
"-qdt" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
Warning: Your C:\Perl\minicpan\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Line-Count header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Caught SIGINT, trying to continue
Warning: Your C:\Perl\minicpan\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Last-Updated header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Got another SIGINT
Reading 'C:\Perl\minicpan\authors\01mailrc.txt.gz'
Use of uninitialized value $command in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Perl\site\lib/CPAN/Tarzip.pm line 161.
"-qdt" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

I'm suspecting this could be because of different carriage returns, but if someone has another idea about why this might be, it would be great. Also if it's because of carriage returns, do you have any idea on how to fix this without downloading the whole repository again on a Windows machine?

Comment: @daxim: thank you but you shouldn't have edited the error message because that's exactly how it shows. I can join a screenshot if you wish.

Comment: Then go ahead and [roll back the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10581304/revisions#rev-arrow-2cabce65-d023-45af-bf34-6289a359ce03).

Answer (score 0):

Delete the CPAN configuration and run its first-time configuration again.

It's still referencing e.g. the Linux path to `tar`, and using ANSI terminal escapes for colours.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very noob to CPAN and Perl configuration. How do I delete the CPAN configuration? And how come the configuration is Linux when this is ActivePerl for Windows?

Comment: Find `CPAN/Config.pm` and `CPAN/MyConfig.pm`, read the [CPAN documentation](http://p3rl.org/CPAN).

Comment: Thanks for the RTFM answer. I deleted both files (MyConfig wasn't created anyway), problem still persists. CPAN doc was no use because it only speaks about *IX systems. I'll just recreate the repository using a Windows machine. Thanks for your help and your time.